# Why is the order of The Chronicles of Narnia changed from original publication?

Tags: c-s-lewis, the-chronicles-of-narnia, reading-order, textual-history

When I originally read *The Chronicles of Narnia* I read an older boxset which has the books numbered in original publication order:

1. The Lion, The Witch, and the Wardrobe
2. Prince Caspian
3. The Voyage of the Dawn Treader
4. The Silver Chair
5. The Horse and His Boy
6. The Magician's Nephew
7. The Last Battle

This was later changed by the publishers to be in chronological order as pertaining to the timeline of Narnia:

1. The Magician's Nephew
2. The Lion, The Witch, and the Wardrobe
3. The Horse and His Boy
4. Prince Caspian
5. The Voyage of the Dawn Treader
6. The Silver Chair
7. The Last Battle

I've never understood the reason for this change and I can't think of any other cases where a series of novels' order was changed by a publisher. What was the reason the publishers decided to make this change in reading order of The Chronicles of Narnia?

Comment: Which publisher is/are your boxset(s) from?

Comment: The older one is published by Macmillan and the newer one is published by HarperCollins

Comment: Yep, that fits with what I wrote in my answer :-)

Comment: One edition of EE Doc Smith's Skylark series had the second book in the series put into the third slot by mistake because the second book of the series is named _Skylark 3_ (they break the first Skylark in the first book and make the Skylark 2 all in the first book).

Comment: If a series adds prequels or "side" stories, it's unusual for people to *not* consume the series in in-universe chronological order after those are available. Consider *Star Wars* - it would be strange to watch 4-6 and only then watch Rogue One afterwards. (YMMV on other episodes, but most people agree the original trilogy and Rogue One are good.)

Comment: @Graham true enough but this is a different case. The novels were published as a series, not as prequels. If this were similar to star wars then we'd have gotten books 2, and then 4-7 and finally 1 and 3. Consider also Wheel of Time series which has a prequel which was written later. The original series are still numbered in the same order because they are part of a series. They didn't change volume 1 to volume 2 when the prequel was published, they just published it as a prequel.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The question of reading order for *The Chronicles of Narnia* is [a complicated one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia#Reading_order), with much debate even among avid fans of the series. But you've asked only **why publishers changed the order**, which is much easier to answer objectively than which order is "best"/preferable.

---

The answer lies in a letter which Lewis wrote, dated April 1957, to a young American fan named Laurence Kreig. The boy preferred internal chronological order (starting with *The Magician's Nephew*) while his mother preferred publication order (starting with *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe*). Lewis said:

> I think I agree with your order for reading the books more than with your mother's. The series was not planned beforehand as she thinks. When I wrote *The Lion* I did not know I was going to write any more. Then I wrote *P. Caspian* as a sequel and still didn't think there would be any more, and when I had done *The Voyage* I felt quite sure it would be the last, but I found I was wrong. So perhaps it does not matter very much in which order anyone read them. I’m not even sure that all the others were written in the same order in which they were published. I never keep notes of that sort of thing and never remember dates.

In C.S. Lewis's *Collected Letters*, Volume 3, pp. 847-8, the following footnote is added to this letter:

> In the summer of 1963 Lewis had Walter Hooper write down the order in which he preferred the stories to be read: *The Magician’s Nephew*; *The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe*; *The Horse and His Boy*; *Prince Caspian*; *The Voyage of the ‘Dawn Treader’*; *The Silver Chair*; and *The Last Battle*. Regarding the order in which the stories were written, see [CG](https://books.google.com.cy/books/about/C_S_Lewis.html?id=6_TtPwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y), ‘The Writing of the Narnias’, pp. 401–5.

---

The US publication rights were originally owned by Macmillan, who preferred the original publication order starting with *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe*. In 1994, Harper Collins took over the US publication rights, and they changed the order to internal chronological order starting with *The Magician's Nephew*. Why? In the 2005 Harper Collins editions, the publishers added the following note:

> Although *The Magician's Nephew* was written several years after C. S. Lewis first began *The Chronicles of Narnia*, he wanted it to be read as the first book in the series. HarperCollins is happy to present these books in the order in which Professor Lewis preferred.

**TL;DR: Lewis himself expressed a preference for internal chronological order, at least a couple of times, and the publishers of later editions decided to follow this.**

<sub>Further reading: Paul Ford, *Companion to Narnia: A Complete Guide to the Magical World of C.S. Lewis's The Chronicles of Narnia*, 2005. Hat-tip also to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia#Reading_order) and [Jon Ericson's blog and comments](https://github.com/jericson/jericson.github.io/issues/14) for guiding me to some useful sources.</sub>

Comment: Great answer and very interesting. I never knew that Lewis himself said he wanted the order changed. This actually slightly changes my opinion about the "correct" order haha. Although I'll probably stick to the order I first read them in.

Comment: There's a LOT of debate about the "correct" order among fans and critics. In fact, asking about the reasons for and against each of the two main orders would make a good new [tag:reading-order] question ...

Comment: There are obviously things to be said in favour of both points of view. But, personally,I would find it very odd if reading the Narnia series for the first time to attempt to read an entire novel _before_ reading _The Lion The Witch and the Wardrobe_. Perhaps the subsequent order is not so important, but it would be baffling to read any novel from the series prior to reading the one which _explains_ what is happening and _introduces_ all the characters.

Comment: In these quotes, at least, it seems more like Lewis was encouraging a young reader to explore literature than expressing his own advocacy for a chronological reordering.

Comment: I'm leaning towards agreement with @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, while Lewis stated the he "thinks" he agrees with the chronological order, he also states that it doesn't matter entirely what order you read them in. The quote then by HarperCollins stating that they are presenting the series in the "order that Lewis preferred" seems to jump from a slightly leaning opinion to some kind of a dying desire to have changed the order.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I think that's the case in the quote to a young reader, but you are neglecting the footnote in *Collected Letters*, which at least as written there says a "preference."

Comment: @Ed999 I don't think your comment makes sense--*The Magician's Nephew* is internally chronologically earlier than TLTWTW, so it in fact introduces and explains aspects of the world and the characters of TLTWTW.

Comment: @ElizaWilson I don't think that follows. *The Magician's Nephew* assumes the reader is already familiar with Narnia. In fact Narnia is mentioned in the very first paragraph, without further explanation (and the narrative doesn't even reach Narnia until halfway through the book). By contrast, in *The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe* the reader is properly introduced to Narnia as Lucy and the other children find out about it.

Comment: I did say there's a lot of debate ... this comment thread is already proving it :-D

Comment: @Randal'Thor https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14969/for-and-against-different-reading-orders-for-narnia

Comment: @EspeciallyLime You are quite right. Regardless of what any author may say, _the_ best order to read _any_ series is publication order. Because that would be the order most fans read it in, and it's the only one that's guaranteed to make sense for all cases. It's the only way to get the true experience of a series, if you know what I mean. Narnia began with The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe. It just did. That's the first book that was published. That's the one that introduced millions of people to Narnia. Read it first.

Comment: @user91988 I generally agree, but there are some counterexamples. Discworld is one IMO - it makes a lot of sense to read the books with the same protagonists (e.g. Tiffany Aching books) consecutively, even though others were written in between. But this example is just another reason to follow publication order for Narnia IMO: Prince Caspian follows on so naturally from the Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe that it seems odd to read the Horse and His Boy in between.

Comment: @ElizaWilson  But your argument implies that it is _necessary_ to read _The Magician's Nephew_ first, which is obviously nonsense because five other books in the series were published before it: i.e. it was originally impossible to read it first, because when the earlier five volumes were published it didn't exist, so _couldn't_ be read. Yet no one was any the worse for that. It adds details, but the details it adds were plainly not necessary for understanding the five books already published, or the series up to that point would not have made sense.